# disadvantages to customizing global navigation for sharepoint 2010 WCM

Tags: navigation, wcm

Hi I am currently working on a project that requires using a custom sitemap provider for the global navigation of a WCM site. My understanding is that this is going to break security trimming and possibly other things. Does anyone have experience with this and can you provide me with information as to what will be affected and how?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons why you might need to create a custom provider.  If you do create a custom provider, you will would need to add the security trimming on within your code.  This is difficult, but not impossible.

MSDN magazine recently had a pretty good overview implementation for a custom provider that leverages the term store to surface the proper content hierarchy to support a WCM site.  You can find that content here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456396.aspx

Comment: really fine piece of information!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 Server provides publishing feature. This feature contains coolest navigation managment functionslity. If you activate this feature you can see Navigation link in Site Settings. This link redirects you to the page of navigation settings. In these settings you can add links, manage audience for created links, etc... I think that it is a powerfull tool to customize top and current (quick launch) menus.